# how does Operating System map port number to process that use it

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, operating-system, serversocket

For a simple python server using TCP socket as below, when there comes a TCP packet, and transport layer get port number, how does OS/transport layer know which thread/process to wake up(assuming the thread/process is blocking because of recv() system call)? for the code below, both parent thread and child thread have the connectionsocket file descriptor, how OS know which one to wake up? Thanks

```
host = 'localhost'
port = 55567
buf = 1024
addr = (host, port)
welcomesocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
welcomesocket.bind(addr)
welcomesocket.listen(2)

while 1:
    connectionsocket, clientaddr = serversocket.accept()
    thread.start_new_thread(handler, (connectionsocket, clientaddr))
serversocket.close()
```

Comment: It depends entirely on how the operating system is implemented. Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

There is an hash map tracking all used port in the kernel space.

When a packet arrives, kernel lookup the table using the port information in the packet, find the associated socket, and notify it

Here is how linux do it http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/udp.c#L489

Comment: thanks, but how does the OS know which thread/process the socket is associated with?

Comment: can you tell me which attr represents process info in socket struct? I checked the socket struct but couldn't find any related information. Thanks

Comment: Actually, it doesn't know which process the socket belongs, because there may be multiple process hold the socket. They only know which process/thread is blocking on the socket

Comment: They don't know, they don't need to know

Comment: check struck sock->sk_wq, there is a wait queue http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/sock.h#L371

Comment: I still don't get it, if OS doesn't know, how OS knows which process/thread should be put into ready queue?

Comment: They don't knwo which process own the socket, they know which thread is blocking on the socket

Comment: @ZangMingJie Of course it knows which process owns the socket. Too much guesswork here. It *might* be a hashtable, for example, or it might be an indexed table with 65535 elements. Or a skip list. Or ...

Comment: @EJP it is only forward lookable, not backward lookable. You can lookup sockets owned by a process, but you cannot find the process which owns the socket

Comment: I don't know what 'forward lookable' and 'backward lookable' are supposed to mean, but if you know the thread you know the process that owns the thread. If you're talking about some specific operating system implementation, I suggest you name it. If not, it sounds like waffle to me.

Comment: Yeah... if the OS is non-trivial, it need to know which process/s own the socket so that it can release it if all the owners terminate.  It also needs to know which threads, if any, are waiting on it so that one can be made ready when a driver signals I/O completion.  The details of the data linkage are OS-dependent.